# How can I get the exact word in a sentence

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

If I do this query, I search on a field that contains :

[Water, coke, 7up]

[Coke, water, 7up]

So, then I want also to return these items even if the parameter is written with capital letter, for this I'm using this `@Query`

```
@Query("SELECT * from drinksList WHERE list LIKE '%'||:name||'%'")
```

What am I missing?

### EDIT

Now I'm using `LIKE %param%`but the problem is that if the table is like this :

[Water, coke, 7up]

[Coke, waterera, 7up]

[Waterg3d, coke, 7up]

[Coke, water23, 7up]

And I want to find the "water" one it will show all of these records, and I just want to find the word "water" doesn't matter if it's lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: But how can I do it to a String like this one `[Water, coke, 7up]` to return this value even if the user types CoKe?

Comment: @CPerkins First option works for me now... this one is not, this is the db I'm using : https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5d24f6455d161js6jxw99v6u

Comment: @CPerkins Perhaps is you that you don't want to think, or to check what's inside the database, it's clear my question, I have entries like the ones from my question, I just want to get the ones that contains "water" and not "waterera" for instance, if you check the link I sent to you you'll find that the database is THE SAME but with other values.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work :-

```
@Query("SELECT * from drinksList WHERE list||',' LIKE '%'||:name||',%' OR list||',' LIKE :name||',%'")
```

This based upon/ was tested using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DrinksList;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DrinksList (list TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO DrinksList VALUES
    ('Water, spicy, coke'),             -- Should be found when searching for water
    ('Coke'),                           -- will not be found when seraching for water
    ('Spicy, water, coke'),             -- Should be found
    ('Coke, spicy, water'),             -- Should be found
    ('wateria, spicyer, cokeer'),       -- should not be found
    ('Water, coke, 7up'),               -- should be found
    ('Coke, waterera, 7up'),            -- should not be found
    ('Waterg3d, coke, 7up'),            -- should not be found
    ('Coke, water23, 7up')              -- should not be found
    ;
SELECT * from drinkslist WHERE list||',' LIKE '%'||'water'||',%' OR list||',' LIKE 'water'||',%';
```

Resulting in :-

[image]

The above has been tested and it does work in room as per :-

All lists displays :-

[image]

Entering **wAtER** in the edit text and clicking the Selective button results in :-

[image]

Entering **7Up** :-

[image]

and so on.

The query being :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM DrinkList WHERE list||',' LIKE '%'||:name||',%' OR list||',' LIKE :name||',%'")
List<DrinkList> getSelectiveDrinks(String name);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer @MikeT I ended up doing it with `collate = NOCASE` the first thing, but with the list is not working this method, so I'm trying to get whatever word is inside that string